# how can i upload files throw servlet into datebase with blob objcet

Tags: java, servlets, file-upload

I want to upload some files throw my website into database. In the upload page, I use some fields like this:

```
<form method = "post" action="addResumeSvl">
   <input type = "file" name="file1">
   <input type = "file" name="file2">
</form>
```

but in the addResumeSvl,how can I distinguish file1 and file2,such like `request.getParameter()` method and then put them into datebase with blob object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your form their must be `multipart`

```
<form action="addResumeSvl" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

now in `post` method add below snippet

```
InputStream inputStream = null; // input stream of the upload file

    // obtains the upload file part in this multipart request
    Part filePart = request.getPart("file1");
    if (filePart != null) {
        // prints out some information for debugging
        System.out.println(filePart.getName());
        System.out.println(filePart.getSize());
        System.out.println(filePart.getContentType());

        // obtains input stream of the upload file
        inputStream = filePart.getInputStream();
    }
```

Now to store in DB use below snippet

```
DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, dbUser, dbPass);

        // constructs SQL statement
        String sql = "INSERT INTO tablename(columnname) values (?)";
        PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);             
        if (inputStream != null) {
            // fetches input stream of the upload file for the blob column
            statement.setBlob(1, inputStream);
        }

        // sends the statement to the database server
        int row = statement.executeUpdate();
        if (row > 0) {
            message = "File uploaded and saved into database";
        }
```

same way do for `file2` file

Answer (score 1):

before you submit your request make sure you add the `enctype="multipart/form-data` as an attribute to the `<form>` tag.

```html
<form action="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type = "file" name="file1">
  <input type = "file" name="file2">
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**If you're on servlet 3.0 or newer** you can use the    `HttpServletRequest#getPart()` to collect multipart form data.

```
@MultipartConfig
public class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Part file1 = request.getPart("file1"); //get your file1
        Part file2 = request.getPart("file2"); // your file2
    }
}
```

After getting your files into variables you can insert them to your database.